# Echoing textbox content into POST request not working

Tags: php, html, post, paypal

I am trying to take the textbox content from "mcname" ($custom) and POST that into "item_name" however it doesn't POST anything? I've looked around, but I still cannot find my solution?

At the top of my script before any HTML:

```
<?php 
$custom = $_post['mcname'];
?>
```

The textbox, form post, and button in the middle of the script.

```
<input type="text" name="mcname" id="mcname" placeholder="Enter your username here…" />
<br/>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="formval">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="__@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $custom; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://__.com/upgrade" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://__.com/upgrade" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://__.com/ipn/ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Iron">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click here to continue to PayPal." ><i class="icon-shopping- cart"></i>Checkout</a>
</form>
```

Comment: $_POST....thats it, not in lowercase ;)

Comment: PHP variable names are cAse-senSITive...

Comment: Yay, Minecraft!  Yes, `$_post` just needs to be `$_POST`.  Case matters in many programming languages, including PHP.  It's probably a good idea to sanitize `$custom` with a function such as `htmlentities`, too.

Answer (score 1):

POST is a super global and must be capitalized:

```
$custom = $_POST['mcname'];
```

Also, your textarea element is outside of your form, it needs to be inside the form tags.

Answer (score 1):

POST is case sensitive, try:

```
$custom = $_POST['mcname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is fine, the problem is:

```
$custom = $_post['mcname'];
```

change it to:

```
$custom = $_POST['mcname'];
```

Comment: @Snaacky run `var_dump($_POST);` and put output here